# Delete unattached many-to-many self-referencing relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What's the best way to delete an unattached entity which has self-referencing relationships?

My example is pretty simple, just a `People` class with a `List<People> Friends` property:

***Edit***: I don't define an extra relationship object but I force Entity Framework to use an extra table:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
        .HasMany(people => people.Friends)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(configuration =>
        {
            configuration
                .MapLeftKey("From_PeopleId")
                .MapRightKey("To_PeopleId")
                .ToTable("Friendships");
        });
}
```

*The schema:*

```
Id Name
== ======
1  Martha
2  Martin
3  Jim

From_PeopleId To_PeopleId
============= ===========
1             2
1             3
3             2
```

*And how I'd like to delete old Jimmy Boy:*

```
using (var context = new FriendsDbContext())
{
    var people = context.Peoples.Find(3);
    context.Peoples.Remove(people);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

SqlException #1:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Friendships_dbo.People_From_PeopleId".
The conflict occurred in database "FriendsDb", table "dbo.Friendships", column 'From_PeopleId'.
```

*My second approach to get rid of old Jimmy boy including his relations:*

```
using (var context = new FriendsDbContext())
{
    var people = context.Peoples
        .Include(p=>p.Friends)
        .Single(p=>p.Id==3);
    context.Peoples.Remove(people);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

SqlException #2:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Friendships_dbo.People_To_PeopleId".
The conflict occurred in database "FriendsDb", table "dbo.Friendships", column 'To_PeopleId'.
```

I know why the `SqlException`s occured (SQL Server is not capable to provide cascade delete allowing the deletion of all relations pointing from and to old Jimmy boy at once). So my question is: **How could I do it with the help of Entity Framework easily?** Easily like `DELETE Friendships WHERE From_PeopleId=3 OR To_PeopleId=3`.

Comment: Did you try to delete the relation in the meantime or before?

Comment: @Daniel No, I didn't. And I still hope that I don't be forced to.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the relations before or in the meantime

```
using (var context = new FriendsDbContext())
{
    var friendships = context.Friendships.Where(x => x.From_PeopleId == 3 || x.To_PeopleId == 3).ToList();
    context.RemoveRange(friendships);

    var people = context.Peoples.Find(3);
    context.Peoples.Remove(people);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I don't have an explicit entity for the many-to-many relationship. No `Friendship` POCO. No `DbSet<Friendship> Friendships` property inside `DbContext`.